# Can i make autolayout js work on canvas / pixijs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to javascript/HTML5

I found that there is a layout library for js called [here](http://ijzerenhein.github.io/autolayout.js/)

it works perfectly on the DOM elements, and the examples provided by the documentation are also for DOM.

Does anyone know if it also work on canvas and how. If it is not , is there any replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can create views using autolayout then it's just a matter of creating a helper class or function that will render out the objects onto the canvas. Providing you know what the elements 'should' be doing on the canvas then it's just a matter of feeding in the values from autolayout.

I could code an example of this but your question is really broad, though I hope this kind of helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @li x, lets say i have an convas inside the html `<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>` assumed that i have handled the canvas to fit the browser with and height  and i have an circle drawn inside the canvas. `var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();` The question for me is that how can i apply the autolayout js to the circle inside the canvas.